# How to dynamically modify list based on values from NgRx store?

Tags: angular, rxjs, ngrx

Still trying to wrap my head around how RxJs/Observables work, so this may be a really basic question.

I'm trying to modify an Angular component (top navbar) to display a link based on a value from the ngrx store. Currently, there's a static array of links in being passed into the navbar component.

There's also a Layout component that initializes this list.

Here's a snippet of what I have:

```
export class LayoutContainer implements OnDestroy {
  links: Link[] = [  // list of links
    {
      label: 'SESSIONS',
      path: '/sessions'
    },
    {
      label: 'BOOKINGS',
      path: '/bookings'
    },
    {
      label: 'ACCOUNT',
      path: '/account'
    }
  ];


constructor( private store: Store<fromAccount.State>
  ) {

    this.clubAdminList$ = store.pipe(
      select(fromAccount.getUserClubAdminList)
    );
  }
```

The 'clubAdminList' is what I'm grabbing from the store. How would I dynamically modify the list of Links based on a value from this clubAdminList?

Answer (score 0):

I'm a bit unsure what type of data is returned by the `getUserClubAdminList`, so I can only give you the broad view.

There are two ways of doing this.

  1.

```
constructor( private store: Store<fromAccount.State>
  ) {

    store.pipe(
      select(fromAccount.getUserClubAdminList)
    ).subscribe(x => {
        this.links = x.map(u => ........ <do whatever you need to adhere to Link interface>
    });
  }
```

  2.

```
<nav class="nav navbar">
    <a *ngFor="clubAdminList$ | async as link" routerLink="{{link.path}}"> {{ link.label }} </a>
</nav>
```

```
constructor( private store: Store<fromAccount.State>
  ) {

    this.clubAdminList$ = store.pipe(
      select(fromAccount.getUserClubAdminList),
      map(x => ........ <do whatever you need to adhere to Link interface> )
    );
  }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer. To clarify a bit, getUserClubAdminList should return an array of clubId strings. I'm really just trying to know whether there's anything in the list at all. Then, this.links I want to add a new link in the case that the list contains any clubId. I'll give your first way a shot. Will I need to unsubscribe as well?

Comment: If you do `.subscribe()`, then yes you have to unsubscribe. Preferably on destroy lifecycle. If you do `async` pipe, you don't have to. It's managed by the pipe